# NTFS permissions to list folders but not show whats inside

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, network-share

Im setting up a backup's shared folder where every user will have its own folder, i want to be able to list all the users folders but only allow each user to work inside his own folder i.e.:

```
Backups folder
|- User 1 folder
|- User 2 folder
|- User 3 folder
|- User N folder
```

Everybody will be able to see all the folders, but only user 1 (and administrators of course) can see and work with the files inside user 1 folder, and the same for all the users (user 2 can only see and work inside user 2 folder...)

How can i adjust the NTFS permissions to allow this behaviour?

Regards...

Answer (score 2):

What you probably ought to do is to enable Access Based Enumeration on the share. Using ABE will allow users to see and work with only the folders that they have permissions to. I don't see why they would need to see any other users folders at all.